# Magento 2 Not getting post varaible from ui component phtml file

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Back again hoping to get some help, I have looked at the magento posts regarding this and have implemented the data-form-part method to no help. Hopefully someone can spot something I can not.

This is my form field set in ui_component/heartfelt_videos_video_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="product_fieldset">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products Used</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="product_container" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Heartfelt\Videos\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Video\Product</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

The Block

```
<?php

namespace Heartfelt\Videos\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Video;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
/**
 * Block template.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_template = 'Heartfelt_Videos::video/product.phtml';

// write your methods here...
private $_video;

/**
 * AssignProducts constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context  $context
 * @param array                                    $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Heartfelt\Videos\Model\Video $video,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_video = $video;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

}

}
```

Do i have to have anything regarding this subject in the block besides the above? From what i have read it does not

The phtml file

```
<?php
$products = $this->getProducts();
?>
<div class="container">

<div id="viewproduct" class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active">Video Products</li>
        <li class="active">Related Products</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-product">
            <div>
                <div class="video-products">
                    <?php 
                    if(!empty($products)) {
                        foreach($products as $product) { ?>
                            <div class="product-item-box rpib-<?php echo $product["entity_id"];?>">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <img  src="<?php echo $product["imageurl"];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <?php echo $product["name"] ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div data-id="<?php echo $product["entity_id"]; ?>" class="delete-product btn btn-danger">X</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php
                        } 
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-related">

        </div>

        <input  data-form-part="heartfelt_videos_video_form" class = "input-text" type="text" name="testvalue" value="Hello World">
    </div>
</div>
```

Form Name

```
<uiComponent name="heartfelt_videos_video_form"/>
```

When i click on save in my form i do not get the post variable technique_id.

I am sure it is something quite dumb but hopefully someone smarter with magento can spot my foolish error.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add Heartfelt\Videos\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Video\Product code inquestion

Comment: Added my the rest of the block code. Thank you for responding @RutveeSojitra

Comment: it seems no error in above code maybe video/product.phtml code can help
Can you please upload it

Comment: So the input is down at the bottom of the phtml file, and its goal will be a hidden field but have it as normal input while i debug

Comment: Heartfelt\Videos\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Video\Product
execute(){
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
die("here);
Can you please paste it and share your output what are you getting?
}

Comment: Probably would help to know. I am using this on admin grid, i am using the block to display some more intricate html, i was hoping to use that hidden field to store some information and then when the forms submits and saves the admin grid it gets picked up

Comment: Ya but you are just stuck in getting post data so that's why i have suggested you

Comment: Putting it in Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Video/Product does not do anything, but i put it in my admin grid save controller and i get all my post variables but do not see that variable

Comment: @RutveeSojitra any other suggetions? I still have not been able to get this to work?